# cannot open the pages I created after deploy/build

Tags: openshift, redhat

As the title says, I cannot open pages after I deploy/build in redhat openshift (starter/free version). I am using the dynamic web application project of eclipse, then uploaded it to github and use the redhat openshift apache tomcat to pull from github.

the directory structure is.

```
/WebContent
./ test.jsp
./ testHTML.html
./ WEB-INF
././ lib
./././ gson jar
./././ mysql connector jar
```

here is the YAML informations:

```
kind: Build
apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  annotations:
    openshift.io/build-config.name: usersystem-mysqlapi
    openshift.io/build.number: '1'
    openshift.io/build.pod-name: usersystem-mysqlapi-1-build
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/build.openshift.io/v1/namespaces/usersystem-mysqlapi/builds/usersystem-mysqlapi-1
  resourceVersion: '4336287'
  name: usersystem-mysqlapi-1
  uid: 24428be3-ace2-11e9-96e9-0a580a8100b5
  creationTimestamp: '2019-07-23T00:38:08Z'
  namespace: usersystem-mysqlapi
  ownerReferences:
    - apiVersion: build.openshift.io/v1
      kind: BuildConfig
      name: usersystem-mysqlapi
      uid: 242c9ec1-ace2-11e9-9305-0a580a8000c1
      controller: true
  labels:
    app: usersystem-mysqlapi
    buildconfig: usersystem-mysqlapi
    openshift.io/build-config.name: usersystem-mysqlapi
    openshift.io/build.start-policy: Serial
spec:
  nodeSelector: null
  output:
    to:
      kind: ImageStreamTag
      name: 'usersystem-mysqlapi:latest'
    pushSecret:
      name: builder-dockercfg-sv867
  resources: {}
  triggeredBy:
    - message: Image change
      imageChangeBuild:
        imageID: >-
          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/httpd@sha256:109a5ab8afbbdff4a65167349d3af4548f8e4ad93e56bb9350670764a49418a9
        fromRef:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          namespace: openshift
          name: 'httpd:2.4'
  strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        name: >-
          image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/httpd@sha256:109a5ab8afbbdff4a65167349d3af4548f8e4ad93e56bb9350670764a49418a9
      pullSecret:
        name: builder-dockercfg-sv867
  postCommit: {}
  serviceAccount: builder
  source:
    type: Git
    git:
      uri: 'https://github.com/redwavefotissimo/UserSystemMySQLAPI.git'
  revision:
    type: Git
    git:
      commit: 16c0f88f596baf9fe0cc0d3eb0a6b62dcf32f087
      author:
        name: /*hide*/
        email: /*hide*/
      committer:
        name: /*hide*/
        email: /*hide*/
      message: init. starting point for jsp api for mysql
status:
  phase: Complete
  startTimestamp: '2019-07-23T00:38:08Z'
  completionTimestamp: '2019-07-23T00:43:50Z'
  duration: 342000000000
  outputDockerImageReference: >-
    image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/usersystem-mysqlapi/usersystem-mysqlapi:latest
  config:
    kind: BuildConfig
    namespace: usersystem-mysqlapi
    name: usersystem-mysqlapi
  output:
    to:
      imageDigest: 'sha256:dff47dd8f0e3921cfd17ddc45cb8d4d33a1698ff22852536046a173e418eda25'
  stages:
    - name: FetchInputs
      startTime: '2019-07-23T00:38:17Z'
      durationMilliseconds: 673
      steps:
        - name: FetchGitSource
          startTime: '2019-07-23T00:38:17Z'
          durationMilliseconds: 673
    - name: PullImages
      startTime: '2019-07-23T00:38:29Z'
      durationMilliseconds: 297868
      steps:
        - name: PullBaseImage
          startTime: '2019-07-23T00:38:29Z'
          durationMilliseconds: 297868
    - name: Build
      startTime: '2019-07-23T00:43:28Z'
      durationMilliseconds: 17631
      steps:
        - name: DockerBuild
          startTime: '2019-07-23T00:43:28Z'
          durationMilliseconds: 17631
    - name: PushImage
      startTime: '2019-07-23T00:43:45Z'
      durationMilliseconds: 3761
      steps:
        - name: PushImage
          startTime: '2019-07-23T00:43:45Z'
          durationMilliseconds: 3761
```

Comment: Can you provide the output from `oc get bc -o yaml`?

Comment: i do not use the console but the web only, how can i get the yaml output from web?

Comment: Go to Builds, select your app, and in the top right select Actions -> Edit YAML. This will give you the same output as `oc get bc -o yaml`

Comment: edited to include YAML information

Comment: follow up, any answer for this one? I just want to open jsp with database connections using red hat openshift